# Number format specifier scheme

Tags: javascript, language-agnostic, string-formatting

I'm looking for a format specifier scheme for *numbers* that bears the characteristics of the ubiquitous "YYYY-MM-DD" etc. format specifiers for dates. I'm looking for:

1. Easy to process: It shouldn't take a lot of effort (algorithmic complexity, performance) to format a number.
2. (Optional) User-friendly: It is intuitive enough for users to directly work with this syntax.
3. Account for thousands separators and decimal places.

Even though my target domain is JavaScript (i.e. formatting `Number` instances), I prefer a specifier scheme that is standard, intuitive etc. instead of JavaScript-native. And no, I don't think the `printf` number format specifiers are intuitive enough to present to users.

The scheme I've come up with so far is:

`#,###.##`

to say:

1. The whole part uses groups of **3** digits separated by **commas**
2. Use **2** decimal places and use a **period** as the delimiter

**I'm feeling "meh" about this scheme** and don't want to invest too much time in implementing it before seeing better alternatives.

What I've also experiemented with is, to be done with a format specifier and actually use a preferences object with distinct properties for thousands/decimal delimiters, number of decimal places etc. and abstract it by presenting to the user sample number outputs to pick from.

Should I forget about using a format specifier scheme and just use a set of properties that are abstracted at presentation layer? Is there a standard(ish) specifier that meets the 3 criteria I mentioned at the top?

At the end of the day, I'm not without a solution and I have enough to get me going. I'm just looking for a more ideal solution.

Comment: "I'm feeling 'meh' about this scheme" Why? I understand that using a standardised scheme would obviously be nicer, but personally I think your proposed scheme looks pretty good. Is there anything specific you dislike with it?

Comment: I also like the look of your proposal. Easily understandable.

Comment: @JonasHöglund I can't think of anything specific. I intuitively thought that an ad-hoc scheme would be bound to have holes. But when I pushed myself to think about the specifics, I saw that this would actually work.

Comment: OK, maybe what I lacked was some encouragement that my proprietary scheme would actually work. I'll put it to the test of an actual implementation and see how it goes.

Comment: This scheme also looks very similar to the [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) scheme in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT is a standard which has a [comprehensive decimal-format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256225.aspx) scheme.

```
format-number(5351,"#,###.##")
```

ECMA-402 is another standard which has a number formatting API:

> A culture-sensitive NumberFormat object can be constructed using the `Intl.NumberFormat` constructor with desired locale tag and options. The format method of the `NumberFormat` object may be used to format numeric data based on the locale and options set. `Number.prototype.toLocaleString` has also been updated to internally use `Intl.NumberFormat` for culture sensitive formatting and now supports two optional arguments - locale and options.

```js
var number = 1123456.789;

// request a US formatted number
console.log("United States: " + new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(number));

// limit to three significant digits
console.log("3 significant digits: " + new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { maximumSignificantDigits: 3 }).format(number));

// request a French formatted number
console.log("France: " + new Intl.NumberFormat('fr-FR').format(number));

// request a Indian formatted number
console.log("India: " + new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN').format(number));
```

A more user friendly solution would be something like the [NumberFormat](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/numberformat.html) or [DecimalFormat](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/DecimalFormat.html) schemes of CFML.

**References**

- [Building world-ready applications in JavaScript using IE11 – IEBlog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2013/11/11/building-world-ready-applications-in-javascript-using-ie11/)
- [Intl.NumberFormat - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)
- [Language subtag lookup app](https://r12a.github.io/app-subtags/)
- [Choosing a language tag](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-choosing-language-tags)
- [W3C I18N Server Setup Techniques](https://www.w3.org/International/techniques/server-setup)